Issue connecting Google Cloud Function to Google VM instantce
I have never use Google Cloud before and this is all pretty new to me but Im trying to set it up anyway. Basically I would like my flow like this:
App -> gcp function -> hits Vm with my postgres db -> return data
Currently:

I CAN hit my function and get a response ('hello world)
and I CAN SSH into the VM and get results from my db
but I CANT seem to hit my VM from my gcp function

I walked through this and I think I have it all correct but Im missing something:
https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/networking/connecting-vpc

I created my VPC network (added firewall to allow port 80 and 5432)
MY VM is connected to this VPC
I created Serverless VPC access and set network to the one above
I created a gcp function to test the connection but it keeps timing out

Here is my function:
const axios = require('axios');

exports.testVpcConnector = async (req, res) => {
  try {
     const response = await axios.get('http://{ VM_INTERNAL_IP_ADDRESS }');
     console.log('RESPONSE-----------------', response)
     // res.send(response.data);
   } catch (error) {
      console.log('ERROR-----------------', error)
      // res.send(`Error: ${error.message}`);
   }
 };

Here is my firewall to allow all:

Here is my VM showing the interal Ip (this is just testing so not worried about showing anything sensitive)

Here is my VM using the default VPC netork

Here is my default VPC network

Here is my VPC connector

And here is my function using the VPC connector

I added axios to the package.json.
Im not really sure what to do next. When I run Test Function it just keeps timing out.

Do you use the private IP of your VM? What's your firewall rules? Do you accept all IP sources?

I use the internal Ip of the VM and I created a firewall with IP ranges 0.0.0.0/0 and Protocols and ports is set to all

I added more info, hopefully it helps

Does your VM have the network-tag allow-all?

I actually found another doc and wiped everything to use that: https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-instance-cloud-functions however I have a new error but feel I am a bit closer. I will create a new SO, not sure if I should delete this or leave it?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78436941/error-connect-econnrefused-127-0-0-1543-connect-to-cloud-sql-for-postgresql-fr
