Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5432 Connect to Cloud SQL for PostgreSQL from Cloud Functions
I am following this doc:
https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-instance-cloud-functions
The docs seem to be a bit off as there is no mention of creating a connector in the cloud function but its required.
I have it working with the helloworld example but when I try to connect to my AlloyDb and fetch users I get this error: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:543
I set my env variables:
INSTANCE_UNIX_SOCKET : /cloudsql/{my-project-id}:us-east4:quickstart-instance 
DB_NAME: {db_name}
DB_USER: {db_user}
DB_PASS: {my_pwd}

I set my Runtime service account to my account with AlloyDb_Admin permissions
Here is my function:
-package.json
{
  "dependencies": {
   "@google-cloud/functions-framework": "^3.0.0",
   "knex": "3.1.0",
   "pg": "8.11.5"
 }
}

-index.js
const Knex = require('knex');

functions.http('getUsers', async (req, res) => {

    const createUnixSocketPool = async config => {

        return Knex({
            client: 'pg',
            connection: {
            user: process.env.DB_USER, // e.g. 'my-user'
            password: process.env.DB_PASS, // e.g. 'my-user-password'
            database: process.env.DB_NAME, // e.g. 'my-database'
            host: process.env.INSTANCE_UNIX_SOCKET, // e.g. '/cloudsql/project:region:instance'
            },
            ...config,
        });
    };

    const knex = await createUnixSocketPool()

    knex('users').select('*')
    .then(rows => {
        console.log(rows);
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.error(err);
    });
}); 

Here is my network:

Here is my Connector Details:

Here is my firewall for default:

What might I be missing?

Cloud SQL and AlloyDB are two different products.
While similar, they are still different and the code sample you are referencing is meant for Cloud SQL and won't work as is for AlloyDB. However, a very similar sample will (an easier to understand one in my opinion).
Since AlloyDB uses a Private IP address by default for the database, I would recommend just connecting directly over a TCP connection to your AlloyDB instance's Private IP address as follows:
You will want to use the env variable INSTANCE_HOST instead of INSTANCE_UNIX_SOCKET and have it be the Private IP address of your instance which you can find on the AlloyDB Overview page
const Knex = require('knex');

functions.http('getUsers', async (req, res) => {
    const knex = Knex({
        client: 'pg',
        connection: {
            host: process.env.INSTANCE_HOST, // AlloyDB IP (ex. 10.0.0.1)
            port: 5432,
            user: process.env.DB_USER,
            password: process.env.DB_PASS,
            database: process.env.DB_NAME,
        },
    });
    await knex('users').select('*')
    .then(rows => {
        console.log(rows);
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.error(err);
    });
});


Hey thanks for commenting. I went to the alloydb cluster page and I see the private Ip  and made the update you suggested and I was still getting the error so I consoled my envs and they were undefined (not sure why that is) so I hard coded the values and now I get this error.
ERROR---------- KnexTimeoutError: Knex: Timeout acquiring a connection. The pool is probably full. Are you missing a .transacting(trx) call? Googling now...

oops, might be due to a missing await before knex('users')

good call on that, unfortunately I get the same error. I set the pool as some suggested: pool: { min: 2, max: 20, idleTimeoutMillis: 30000  } but its a no go.

Could it be a Knex issue and I try something else?

Tried sequalize and I get a timeout error: connect ETIMEDOUT 10.127.192.5:5432 I don't mind the Ip being here. Once I get things working it will all be changed. Just trying to get something to work right now.

timeout points at the fact that maybe your network setup is not correct as the connectivity seems to not be working. Double check that your AlloyDB cluster Private VPC network matches that of the VPC Connector.

When you say matches that of the VPC connector do you mean, make sure its allowed in the firewall? If so I set the firewall to allow everything for the time being.
